# Code::Blocks is it alive?

Tags: codeblocks

I would like to ask you guys if Code::Blocks project is still being developed? I'm asking because I've downloaded lates ver 10.05 and I really like it (much more than VS2010) but it was released good while ago, and I couldn't find any info about next release.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. Just look [at the SVN logs](http://svn.berlios.de/wsvn/codeblocks/trunk?op=log&isdir=1&). The latest commit was today. I didn't find anything about the planned release schedule though.

Comment: "Nightly" builds are also posted on the [forums](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?board=20.0).

Comment: @Francis Thanks for this link. Fantastic! I think in home I will do everything (or try to) with code::blocks from now on. It is just fantastic, and so much smoother (runs much faster) than VS2010. Thanks again. +1